# Explode in one line

Tags: php, explode

I want to explode text word by word, but in one line. Not line by line.
I've got this:

```
$someWords = "Please don't blow me to pieces."; 
$test = '';
$wordChunks = explode(" ", $someWords);
for($i = 0; $i < count($wordChunks); $i++){
    echo "Piece $i = $wordChunks[$i] <br />";
    $test .='<a href="test.php?id='.$wordChunks[$i].'">'.$wordChunks[$i].'</a> <br />';
}
```

and this:

```
 echo $test;
```

With this it look like this :

```
Please
don't
blow
me
to
pieces
```

But i want it this way:

```
Please don't blow me to pieces
```

And every word have a link.

Comment: I don't see any difference between what you're getting and what you want...

Comment: Now I see it. The way you want is the same than the original string...

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `<br />` tag

```
echo "Piece $i = $wordChunks[$i] ";
$test .='<a href="test.php?id='.$wordChunks[$i].'">'.$wordChunks[$i].'</a> ';
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason it separates onto new lines is because you put them it. Just remove the `<br>`s:

```
$test .='<a href="test.php?id='.$wordChunks[$i].'">'.$wordChunks[$i].'</a>';
```

**EDIT**

You can actually do this in one line with a Regex:

```
$test = preg_replace(
  '/(\S+)(\s*)/', // Find every collection of non-whitespace characters, which may or may not be followed by whitespace
  '<a href="test.php?id=$1">$1</a>$2', // Replace it with a link and append whitespace, if any
  htmlspecialchars($someWords, ENT_QUOTES) // pass the input string through htmlspecialchars() to avoid broken HTML
);
```

[See it working](http://codepad.viper-7.com/dWyO5c)

Answer (score 1):

`<br/>` means a line break. So, if you don't want a new line between each word, don't put a `<br/>` between each word.

So, instead of

```
$test .='<a href="test.php?id='.$wordChunks[$i].'">'.$wordChunks[$i].'</a> <br />';
```

do

```
$test .='<a href="test.php?id='.$wordChunks[$i].'">'.$wordChunks[$i].'</a>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `array_map` for this (and `implode` to glue everything back into a string):

```
$someWords = "Please don't blow me to pieces."; 
$words = explode(" ", $someWords);
$links = array_map(
    $words,
    function($w) { return '<a href="test.php?id='.$w.'">'.$w.'</a>'; });
echo implode('', $links);
```

You can do it in one line if you don't mind the readability.

Answer (score 0):

You're including line breaks manually. Simply remove `<br />`:

```
$someWords = "Please don't blow me to pieces."; 
$test = '';
$wordChunks = explode(" ", $someWords);
for($i = 0; $i < count($wordChunks); $i++){
    echo "Piece $i = $wordChunks[$i] <br />";
    $test .='<a href="test.php?id='.$wordChunks[$i].'">'.$wordChunks[$i].'</a>';
} //                                                                         ^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$someWords = "Please don't blow me to pieces.";
$test = '';
$wordChunks = explode(" ", $someWords);
for($i = 0; $i < count($wordChunks); $i++){
    $test .='<a href="test.php?id='.$wordChunks[$i].'">'.$wordChunks[$i].'</a>&nbsp;';
} 
echo $test;
```